# QTextBrowser и встроенные изображения

Tags: c++, qt5

Заметил, что при загрузке в QTextBrowser текст html-документа, содержащего встроенные изображения, типа:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,тут-кодированное-изображение-по-base64==">
```

Во время запуска в консоль вылетает предупреждение:

```
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
```

И тем не менее, все работает, все отображает. Но хотелось бы без таких вот сообщений. Куда копать, как обработать данную ситуацию?

Версия Qt 5.7.0, mingw32 - x32, сборка с сайта

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43270

Comment: ясно, пасип :-\

Comment: Да не за что :)

Comment: @isnullxbh , если вдруг понадобится, решение ниже ...)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Решение**

Пока [баг](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43270) не закрыли, можно эту ситуацию обработать, наследуясь от QTextBrowser, и допиливая обработчик QTextBrowser::loadResource. Тогда получается все по фэншую:

```
QVariant MyTextBrowser::loadResource(int type, const QUrl &url) {
  if (type == QTextDocument::ImageResource
    && url.scheme() == QLatin1String("data")) {
    QRegExp Rx("^image/[^;]+;base64,(.+)$");
    if (Rx.indexIn(url.path())>=0) {
      QImage Image;
      if (Image.loadFromData(QByteArray::fromBase64(Rx.cap(1).toLatin1())))
        return QVariant::fromValue(Image);
    }
  }
  return QTextBrowser::loadResource(type, url);
}
```

Конечно, регэксп можно допилить, чтобы он контролировал еще и тип картинки. Но учитывая утверждения из RFC2045:

> Thus, a media type of "image/xyz" is enough to tell a user agent that the data is an image, even if the user agent has no knowledge of the specific image format "xyz".

И документации по [QImage::loadFromData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qimage.html#loadFromData-1):

> The loader attempts to read the image using the specified format, e.g., PNG or JPG. If format is not specified (which is the default), the loader probes the file for a header to guess the file format.

... я решил регэксп не обременять контролем типов изображения, смысла особого нет.

Вопрос решен.